# How to call custom jquery function onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi. I am new to jQuery.. I want to know how to call custom jQuery function by onClick attribute of HTML. This was the basic I was trying.Further I want to make  parametrised function and want to call that function onClick attribute.

my jQuery function is:

```
jQuery.fn.myFadeIn=function() {
    return $('#fadeInDiv').fadeIn();
};
```

and the HTML is:

```
<input type="radio" name="contentCalls" class="radioButton" id="Calls" onclick="myFadeIn();">

<div id="fadeInDiv">
div to open
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This plugin `alert()`s the ID of each matched element:

```
jQuery.fn.alertElementId = function()
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        alert(this.id);
    });
};
```

And to use it:

```
// alert() each a-element's ID
$("a").click(function ()
{
    $(this).alertElementId();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace:

```
jQuery.fn.myFadeIn=function() { return $('#fadeInDiv').fadeIn(); };
```

With:

```
var myFadeIn=function() { return $('#fadeInDiv').fadeIn(); };
```

(Assuming you are running this in the global scope)

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign this custom function to some element's click handler, as in:

```
$("#Calls").click($.myFadeIn);
```

What is important to note is that the function you have added to jQuery through its jQuery.fn syntax should be available as part of the $ or jQuery JavaScript objects.